# how to switch the action of execution of script between the terminals in the python script?

Tags: python, unix, vi

I want to run a script that contains some commands to execute for eg: pwd, xterm home, date, time Here i want to run the script which executes pwd in first terminal, and creates a xterm home then in xterm home terminal i want to run date and time command then i want to run once again pwd in main terminal.
"How to switch between the terminals in a python script ?"

Thanks n Regards

Vasantkumar.R.Nagoor

Answer (score 0):

Have your script `myscript.py` take an optional argument e.g. `other_term`.  Spawn `xterm -e myscript.py other_term`.  When the second instance of `myscript.py` starts, check for the optional argument `other_term`; if present, perform the second set of commands.  Use environment variables or files or command line arguments or pipes to transfer any required state between the first (initial) and second (`other_term`) instances. When the `other_term` instance finishes, the second `xterm` will automatically close and return control to the first (intial) instance which can then proceed with its commands.  If you do NOT want the second `xterm` to close then spawn `xterm -e` asynchronously and do NOT let your `other_term` script exit; have it signal instead (e.g. via a semaphore file or, if you know how to do it, via pipe -- `xterm` does not close filehandles) to the first instance that the first instance can resume, and e.g. wait for user confirmation before exiting on both scripts.